# Redirect add to cart

Tags: redirect, magento-1.9

I'm trying to disable the redirection to cart when you clicking on add to cart. I use magento 1.9.0.1. I heave searched on the internet for an anwser. The only option i find is to go to system->configuration->checkout and then disable the redirection. But when go to system->configuration i can't find the checkout. It should be under sale but it's not there. Does anyone know where i can find the checkout or how i can disable te redirection to cart after i click the 'add to cart'button.
Tnx!

Comment: somehow the checkout returned in the configuration. My configuration looks like the picture again.  tnx anyway for the fast responds!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its's possible the website/store view is different to the default settings.

To change, In the top left corner, select the store under the "Configuration Scope".
change it again there...

Answer (score 0):

I think Its something wrong. I used magento 1.9.0.1 and used this chekout tab.
Please see one more time. I share a image which you can see the proper tab.

[image]